# Check total number of collections in arangodb in PHP

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-php

How can I check the total number of collections in arangodb in PHP?

This is what I tried:

```
$documents = $collectionHandler->all($collectionId);

var_dump($documents);
```

Comment: Is there any progress or other feedback you can provide? Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of collections present, you can use `CollectionHandler::getAllCollections()` for this purpose:

```
// create the connection as usual
$handler = new \triagens\ArangoDb\CollectionHandler($connection);
$collections = $handler->getAllCollections();
$collectionNames = array_values($collections);
$collectionCount = count($collectionNames);
```

To get the number of documents in a collection, as your code example suggests, use `CollectionHandler::count($collection)`